# Как вывести число с определенным количеством цифр после запятой С++

Tags: c++

Здраствуйте, я начинающий программист на C++, сижу на нем больше месяца и у нас в университете скоро будут соревнования по программированию. Сейчас я активно готовлюсь и решаю задачи с Online Judge. На второй задаче(ссылка на задачу https://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1001) у меня возникла проблема: не могу вывести число с каким то количеством цифр после запятой. Пробовал делать отдельную функцию, которая вычисляла сколько цифр после запятой у числа, но выходило у меня криво и работало вообще не так как я планировал. Может кто нибудь что нибудь подсказать по поводу того как можно вывести некоторое количество цифр после запятой ДАЖЕ ЕСЛИ ОНО НЕ ДОЛЖНО СОДЕРЖАТЬ ЦИФРЫ ПОСЛЕ ЗАПЯТОЙ(int)?

Comment: Вам не подошло решение по ссылке? Может быть, стоило покопаться в iomanip? https://cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/

Comment: я нашел другое решение, спасибо